# if $\mu(X)=1$ , $f\in L^1$, then $f\in L^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, holder-inequality

if $\mu(X)=1$ , $f\in L^1$, then is true that $f\in L^\infty$?

Basically, I was wondering if I can write
$$\int_X f d\mu \le \mu(X). \|f\|_\infty < \infty$$

or can we claim $\|f\|_\infty =1$? I'm thinking in the eyes of probability that f can at most take value of 1.

but if yes how to prove it?

Comment: Your inequality could be used to show the converse: if $f\in L^\infty$, then $f\in L^1$ (if $\mu(X)$ is finite). What you want, however, is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  For example, $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $X = (0,1]$ has $f \in L^1 \setminus L^\infty$